# Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation error while accessing event log

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, asmx

I have a Windows Service in C# which creates an Event Log like so:

```
public partial class WizardService : ServiceBase
{
    public WizardService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Setup logging
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("WizardService"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "WizardService", "WizardServiceLog");
        }

        eventLog1.Source = "WizardService";
        eventLog1.Log = "WizardServiceLog";
    }
```

The Windows Service can access this Event Log successfully.  The Windows Service is configured to run as Local Service.  This needs to work on Win7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

However, the Service also makes calls out to an ASMX Web Service.  I would like the ASMX Web Service to also be able to access the same Event Log but I get this error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
  at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
  at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
  at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.GetEventLogRegKey(String machine, Boolean writable)
  at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate)
  at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.SourceExists(String source, String machineName, Boolean wantToCreate)
  at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName, String currentMachineName)
  at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
  at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message)
```

Here is the code that the ASMX Web Service uses:

```
public class WizardService : WebService
{
    private EventLog eventLog;

    public WizardService()
    {
        eventLog = new EventLog("WizardServiceLog", "localhost", "WizardService");
    }

    private SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Error : " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the eventLog.WriteEntry() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the `AppPool` that your web service is running under does not have sufficient permissions to access the Event Log.

Best practice is to create a user that has **JUST** the right amount of access without allowing everything. This way if someone hacks your service they don't have full-rights etc.

However, that said, to start with assign `Network Service` or a `Full Admin Rights` user to the `AppPool` and check the Event Log is accessible and then tweak permissions as required.